# upload a default image through input type=file

Tags: java, html, servlets

So, I have a user registration page and want an image to be displayed by default in the page and that image should be uploaded to the database if the user is not changing the image.
What I have done is in the preview div, just wrote the image tag to display the picture and set the value of the input type to an image which is in a specific folder. So here is how the code is looking like

```
<div id="list">
    <img src="backimages/dp.png">
</div>
<input type="file" name="file" id="files" value="backimages/dp.png">
```

when I hit the submit button dp.png is not being store in the database, but when I chose a file by clicking on the choose file button that is successfully being uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be doing this.
Instead, in your server, where you accept the image, you should check whether it is empty and if this is the case use your default image.